# Confused about node-mongodb-native syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm just getting into node and mongodb and came across the first obstacle.

I'm walking through a tutorial where the code looks something like this:

```
var db = new mongo.Db("database", new mongo.Server(host, port, {}));
db.open(function(error){
  db.collection("user", function(err, collection){
    collection.find({"id":"1"}, function(error, cursor){
      cursor.toArray(function(err, users){
        if(users.length == 0){
          console.log("no such user");
        } else if {
          console.log("user found: ", users[0]);
        }
     });
   });
 });
```

However the code failed to work saying that **users** is null. (I do have a code where it inserts entries) Anyway, while trying to figure out what's going on, I've come across the documentation where it uses a synchronous pattern for **find** instead of using callback to retrieve cursor. The code goes something like this:

```
var cursor = collection.find({"id":"1"});
```

In fact, I cannot find anywhere in the documentation where it mentions a usage of **find** with a callback that returns a cursor. I am really confused. Is the tutorial outdated? And what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

If `users` is `null`, then it's likely that `err` is indicating what the problem is.  Add an `if (err)` path to your code to log `err` when it's set.

`find` can work in both ways that you describe.  The callback parameter is optional and if you don't provide it you can use the cursor that's returned instead.  See the docs: [link](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find).